# Como concatenar linhas?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Como concatenar todos os resultados de uma `query` no SQL Server a fim de retornar toda a informação em uma variável?

Por exemplo, considerando uma tabela `cliente` com a seguinte composição:

```
╔═══╦════════════╗
║   ║ Nome       ║
╠═══╬════════════╣
║ 1 ║ José       ║
║ 2 ║ Luis       ║
║ 3 ║ Antônio    ║
╚═══╩════════════╝
```

O resultado desejado seria:

```
José, Luis, Antonio
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uma forma (anterior ao SQL 2012) é utilizar uma variável para concatenar os resultados da linha da seguinte forma:

```
DECLARE @texto varchar(max);

SELECT @texto = ISNULL(@texto + ', ', '') + cli.nome
  FROM cliente cli;

print @texto;
```

Onde o `ISNULL` garante que a vírgula só será inserida caso exista valor anterior atribuído a variável (No caso começando a colocar a vírgula apenas após o `José`).

---

Uma outra forma é usar a sintaxe `FOR XML PATH('')`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING((SELECT ',' + cli.nome AS [text()]
                             FROM cliente cli
                              FOR XML PATH ('')), 2, 8000) AS texto
  FROM cliente cli2
```

---

A partir da versão `2017` do `SQL Server` você pode utilizar a função `STRING_AGG`:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(cli.nome, ',') AS texto
  FROM cliente cli;
```

---

> [`STRING_AGG`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2016)
>
> Concatena os valores das expressões de cadeia de caracteres e coloca os valores de separador entre eles. O separador não é adicionado ao final da cadeia de caracteres.

**Referências:**

- Resposta para a pergunta [**SQL, How to Concatenate results?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1339805/3388148) no SOen;
- Resposta para a pergunta [**Concatenate many rows into a single text string?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/545672/3388148) no SOen;
- [**Script funcional disponível no GitHub.**](https://github.com/Sorackb/StackOverflowPT/blob/master/MSSQL/Concatenar%20resultados%20(203992).sql)