# Unir Nomes em uma linha

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, sql-server-2008, concatenação-de-string

Boa tarde utilizamos o SQL SERVER 2008 como servidor oficial de banco de dados e possuimos a seguinte consulta :

```
SELECT P.NOME              AS [PROFESSOR],
       STIPOCURSO.NOME       AS [NÍVEL DE ENSINO],
       SPL.CODPERLET         AS [ANO],
       STURMA.NOME           AS [TURMA],
       STURNO.NOME           AS [TURNO],
       SD.NOME               AS [DISCIPLINA],
       SPT.AULASSEMANAISPROF AS [AULAS SEMANAIS]
FROM   SPROFESSOR SP (NOLOCK)
       INNER JOIN PPESSOA P
         ON P.CODIGO = SP.CODPESSOA
       INNER JOIN SPROFESSORTURMA SPT (NOLOCK)
         ON SP.CODCOLIGADA = SPT.CODCOLIGADA
            AND SP.CODPROF = SPT.CODPROF
       INNER JOIN STURMADISC ST (NOLOCK)
         ON SPT.CODCOLIGADA = ST.CODCOLIGADA
            AND SPT.IDTURMADISC = ST.IDTURMADISC
       INNER JOIN SPLETIVO SPL (NOLOCK)
         ON ST.IDPERLET = SPL.IDPERLET
            AND ST.CODCOLIGADA = SPL.CODCOLIGADA
       INNER JOIN STURNO (NOLOCK)
         ON ST.CODCOLIGADA = STURNO.CODCOLIGADA
            AND ST.CODTURNO = STURNO.CODTURNO
       INNER JOIN SDISCIPLINA SD (NOLOCK)
         ON ST.CODCOLIGADA = SD.CODCOLIGADA
            AND ST.CODDISC = SD.CODDISC
       INNER JOIN STIPOCURSO (NOLOCK)
         ON SD.CODTIPOCURSO = STIPOCURSO.CODTIPOCURSO
            AND SD.CODCOLIGADA = STIPOCURSO.CODCOLIGADA
       INNER JOIN STURMA (NOLOCK)
         ON ST.CODTURMA = STURMA.CODTURMA
            AND SPL.IDPERLET = STURMA.IDPERLET
WHERE  STURMA.CODCOLIGADA = :CODCOLIGADA1
       AND STURMA.IDHABILITACAOFILIAL = :IDHABILITACAOFILIAL1
       AND STURMA.IDPERLET = :IDPERLET1
       AND STURMA.CODTURMA = :CODTURMA1
GROUP  BY P.NOME,
          STIPOCURSO.NOME,
          SPL.CODPERLET,
          STURMA.NOME,
          STURNO.NOME,
          SPT.AULASSEMANAISPROF,
          SD.NOME
```

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer com que o campo P.NOME se agrupasse de acordo com a disciplina, ou seja, independete se a disciplina possui mais de um professor o nome de ambos sejam retornados na mesma linha

Comment: como a função `string_agg` não está disponível para a versão que você utiliza, acho que o processo fica mais complicado. Veja se ajuda: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Comment: Vou tentar essa sugestão, só o problema é adaptar a consulta nas opções que o link oferece.

Comment: Relacionada: [Concatenar resultados](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203992/concatenar-resultados).

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um exemplo mínimo, somente usando as tabelas necessárias para o exibir os professores da disciplina, nesse exemplo faço um `subselect` e concateno os resultados em uma única linha.

Simulei o mínimo do seu ambiente no *SQLFiddle* para poder demonstrar, clique  no link para visualizar.

[SQLFiddle - Exemplo online:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/07de1/35)

```
SELECT 
   STUFF(
      (SELECT ',' + CAST(PPESSOA.NOME AS VARCHAR(MAX))
      FROM SPROFESSORTURMA AS SPT2
      JOIN SPROFESSOR
        ON SPT2.CODPROF = SPROFESSOR.CODPROF
      JOIN PPESSOA
        ON PPESSOA.CODPESSOA = SPROFESSOR.CODPESSOA
      WHERE SPT2.IDTURMADISC = SPT.IDTURMADISC
      FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'')    AS [PROFESSORES],
   SD.NOME       AS [DISCIPLINA]
FROM SPROFESSORTURMA SPT
LEFT JOIN STURMADISC ST
   ON SPT.IDTURMADISC = ST.IDTURMADISC
LEFT JOIN SDISCIPLINA SD
   ON ST.CODDISC = SD.CODDISC
LEFT JOIN STURMA
   ON ST.CODTURMA = STURMA.CODTURMA
GROUP BY STURMA.NOME
  , SD.NOME
  , SPT.IDTURMADISC
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Da maneira ao qual propôs até o momento me ajudou bastante. Vou finalizar mais alguns testes e dando certo marco sua resposta como efetiva. Obrigado!

Comment: Um adendo, no retorno da consulta o caracter ',' sai antes do primeiro nome e no final do ultimo nome. Ajustei apenas no final FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 1, '') para o caso do TOTVS

Comment: @NathannL.J.LimaAlcantara esses dias fui realizar esse comando aqui, e percebi que só é necessário colocar `2,1` se no `SELECT` tiver um espaço do lado da vírgula, exemplo: `(SELECT ' ,' + `.