# Como fazer PIVOT de uma coluna, concatenando strings em SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Olá, estou fazendo uma consulta em uma base de dados para identificar todas as colunas que são `primary key`'s das tabelas de uma base de dados e também identificar se as mesmas são ou não `identity`. Para isso eu uso a query abaixo:

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(C.OBJECT_ID) AS TABLE_NAME, 
    COL_NAME(C.OBJECT_ID,C.column_id) AS COLUMN_NAME,
    COLUMNPROPERTY(C.OBJECT_ID,COL_NAME(C.OBJECT_ID,C.column_id),'IsIdentity') IS_IDENTITY
FROM 
    sys.indexes I
INNER JOIN  sys.index_columns C ON 
    (I.OBJECT_ID = C.OBJECT_ID) AND
    (I.index_id = C.index_id)
WHERE 
    (i.is_primary_key = 1)
ORDER BY
    OBJECT_NAME(C.OBJECT_ID)
```

O meu problema é que, existem tabelas na base de dados que podem conter chaves primárias conjuntas, tendo o resultado abaixo:

```
+------------+-------------+-------------+
| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | IS_IDENTITY |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
| Foo        | Id          |           1 |
| Bar        | Id          |           1 |
| Bin        | FooId       |           0 |
| Bin        | BarId       |           0 |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

A única forma que eu conheço de resolver isso seria com um `PIVOT`, o problema é que não sei trabalhar muito bem com o mesmo.

Como faço para ter todas as colunas que são `primary key`'s de uma tabela dentro da mesma célula como em um array (separado por vírgula)?

Comment: Qual a versão do seu `SQL Server`?

Comment: Estou rodando no SQLServer 2016

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Concatenar resultados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203992/concatenar-resultados)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partir da versão 2017 do `SQL Server` você pode usar a função [`STRING_AGG`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2016) que permite agrupar e concatenar resultados:

```
SELECT x.TABLE_NAME,
       STRING_AGG(x.COLUMN_NAME, ', ') AS COLUMN_NAMES
  FROM (
  -- Sua query
  ) x
 GROUP BY x.TABLE_NAME;
```

Uma solução simples para versões anteriores é criar uma função:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_chaves(@object_id INT)
  RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @texto NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

  SELECT @texto = @texto + ',' + COL_NAME(C.OBJECT_ID,C.column_id) AS COLUMN_NAME
    FROM sys.indexes I
        INNER JOIN sys.index_columns C ON I.OBJECT_ID = C.OBJECT_ID
                                      AND I.index_id = C.index_id
  WHERE i.is_primary_key = 1
    AND C.OBJECT_ID = @object_id;

  RETURN @texto;
END;
```

E utilizar da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT t.name,
      fn_chaves(t.object_id) AS chaves
  FROM sys.tables t
```