# SELECT com tabela intermediária retornando todos os valores no mesmo campo e separados por vírgula

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Tenho as tabelas (e seus relacionamentos) do diagrama abaixo:[image: Diagrama]

Eu preciso fazer o seguinte:
Trazer todos os campos da tabela TBCADCRE e uma coluna extra chamada ADQ com todos os TIPADQ que o usuário possui (pode ter no máximo 6) separados por ",".

Para melhorar o entendimento, eu fiz um select com as 3 tabelas, mas ele retorna uma linha para cada TIPADQ que o usuário possui (imagem abaixo).

[image: ADQs]

Eu preciso trazer uma única linha e todos os TIPADQs dentro do mesmo campo separados por ",". Ex: CIELO,STONE,POS...

Alguém pode me ajudar? Obrigado.

Comment: Pode sempre dentro de um `loop` ou `cursor` preencher a coluna `TIPADQ` concatenando todas as linhas numa só.

Comment: Obrigado João! Vou pesquisar sobre loop no SQL e depois atualizo aqui! ;)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Concatenar resultados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203992/concatenar-resultados)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após várias tentativas e erros, resolvi da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]