# Unir dados de coluna em linha - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho a seguinte situação:

```
Usuario_A     telefone1
Usuario_A     telefone2
Usuario_A     telefone3
```

Como posso fazer para que quando eu fizer um select, tenha a seguinte saída:

```
+-----------+----------------------------------+
| Usuario_A |  telefone1, telefone2, telefone3 |
+-----------+----------------------------------+
```

No MySQL eu sei que tenho a função `GROUP_CONCAT`, mais para SQL Server não identifiquei algo que possa me ajudar a solucionar.

Comment: Seria interessante você colocar um exemplo mais concreto com a estrutura da tabela, dados de exemplo na tabela e os valores de saida esperados. O `group_concat` une os dados de linha em coluna e no titulo da sua pergunta está o contrário disso. Se quiser use o [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) para colocar o exemplo que funcionaria no MySQL

Comment: Se a versão do SQL Server for 2017 (ou mais recente), pode utilizar STRING_AGG

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como concatenar linhas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203992/como-concatenar-linhas)

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso:

```
SELECT Usuario, Telefone1 [TELEFONE] FROM tbUsuario
UNION ALL
SELECT Usuario, Telefone2 [TELEFONE] FROM tbUsuario
UNION ALL
SELECT Usuario, Telefone3 [TELEFONE] FROM tbUsuario
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `STUFF ()` com `FOR XML PATH`

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  [User] VARCHAR(45),
  Phone VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('Usuario_A', 'telefone1'),
('Usuario_A', 'telefone2'),
('Usuario_A', 'telefone3'),
('Usuario_B', 'telefone4');

SELECT T1.[User],
       STUFF(
              (
                SELECT ',' + T2.Phone
                FROM T T2
                WHERE T2.[User] = T1.[User]
                FOR XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) Phones
FROM T T1
GROUP BY T1.[User];
```

**Retorna:**

```
+-----------+-------------------------------+
|   User    |            Phones             |
+-----------+-------------------------------+
| Usuario_A | telefone1,telefone2,telefone3 |
| Usuario_B | telefone4                     |
+-----------+-------------------------------+
```