# Sql - Concatenar valores se campo for igual

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

tenho o seguinte select:

```
SELECT c.codigo
      ,c.situacao
      ,c.fk_aluno
  FROM       tb_cad   AS c
  INNER JOIN tb_aluno AS a ON c.fk_aluno = a.id 
  order by c.fk_aluno
```

Preciso quando `c.fk_aluno` for igual, aglutinar todos os `c.codigo` em uma unica linha.

Exemplo de retorno do select acima:

```
17162   A   74
17045   A   75
17177   A   75
17175   A   75
17174   A   75
17182   I   75
```

Preciso que se `c.fk_aluno` for repetido, juntar em uma linha e concatenar

```
17162   A   74
17045 A, 17177 A,17175 A, 17174 A, 17182 I  75
```

Utilizo SQL Server 2012

Comment: Informe para nós qual o seu banco de dados! Assim podemos te ajudar de uma forma melhor...

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: Beleza, quando for assim edita sua pergunta e poem essas informações lá, você pode fazer por [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/367008/edit)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Concatenar resultados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203992/concatenar-resultados)

Comment: Mas quer tudo na mesma coluna? Ou as colunas `codigo` e `situacao` fica numa só coluna e a `fk_aluno` numa outra separada?

Comment: codigo e situacao fica numa só coluna e a fk_aluno numa outra separada

Comment: Se a resposta abaixo resolve o seu problema, dê um UP e marque-a como certa! (dou esta indicação aqui porque o @user141448 editou a minha resposta a informar que resolveu o problema).

Answer (score 0):

Tendo em conta a questão e os comentários, penso que isto resolverá o seu problema:

```
SELECT      STUFF(
                    (
                        SELECT  ', ' + codigo + '   ' + situacao
                        FROM    tb_cad
                        WHERE   (fk_aluno = C.fk_aluno) 
                        FOR     XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
                , 1, 2, '') AS CodigoSituacao
        ,   C.fk_aluno
FROM        tb_cad   C
INNER JOIN  tb_aluno A ON C.fk_aluno = A.id 
GROUP BY    C.fk_aluno
ORDER BY    C.fk_aluno
```

Uma outra forma será utilizar a sugestão que o [@Sorak](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/59479/sorack) deu no *link* em comentário (sem a utilização do `STUFF`):

```
SELECT      SUBSTRING(
                        (
                            SELECT  ', ' + codigo + '   ' + situacao
                            FROM    tb_cad
                            WHERE   (fk_aluno = C.fk_aluno) 
                            FOR     XML PATH('')
                        ), 2, 8000) AS CodigoSituacao
        ,   C.fk_aluno
FROM        tb_cad   C
INNER JOIN  tb_aluno A ON C.fk_aluno = A.id 
GROUP BY    C.fk_aluno
ORDER BY    C.fk_aluno
```