# Agrupar uma lista de conversão dentro do SELECT

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Tenho uma duvida no `SQL Server`, tenho uma tabela produto e outra com uma lista de conversão para cada produto tenho uma lista de conversão para aquela produto. preciso de uma lista de produto com os codigos de conversão daquele produto como a imagem a baixo a cada conversão separo por `**` Os que não tiver codigo de conversão mostrar em branco

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

codigo sql

```
SELECT p.ID_Produto,p.CodigoInterno, p.Descricao, p.Localizacao, p.EstoqueAtual, c.IDProduto, c.Codigo FROM TB_Produtos AS p JOIN tb_produtoConversao AS c ON ID_Produto = IDProduto
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

não aparece os produtos que não tem conversão e mostra separados tentei usar groub by mais da erro

```
select p.ID_Produto,p.CodigoInterno, p.Descricao, p.Localizacao, p.EstoqueAtual, c.IDProduto, c.Codigo from TB_Produtos as p join tb_produtoConversao as c on ID_Produto = IDProduto  GROUP BY p.ID_Produto
```

Tabela Produtos

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_Produtos](
[ID_Produto] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CodigoInterno] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
[Localizacao] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Descricao] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
[CodigoCompra] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[DescricaoCompra] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
[ValorCompraProduto] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
[DataUltimaEntrada] [datetime] NULL,
[DataUltimaSaida] [datetime] NULL,
[DescricaoFaturamento] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Marca] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[EstoqueMinimo] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
[EstoqueAtual] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
[PrecoTabelaA] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
[PrecoTabelaB] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
[PrecoTabelaC] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
[AlicotaIBPT] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
[IVA] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
[ReducaoICMS] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
[AlicotaIPI] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
[Observacao] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[DataInclusao] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[ID_UsuarioInclusao] [int] NOT NULL,
[DataAlteracao] [datetime] NULL,
[ID_UsuarioAlteracao] [int] NULL,
[Conversao] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[ID_Unidade] [int] NOT NULL,
[GiroMensal] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
[IDUltimoFormecedorCompra] [int] NOT NULL,
[DataUltimaCompra] [datetime] NULL,
[NCM] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[CST] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
```

Tabela Conversao

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_ProdutoConversao](
[IDConversao] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Codigo] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Descricao] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[DtExclusao] [datetime] NULL,
[IdUsuarioExcluiu] [int] NULL,
[DataInclusao] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[ID_UsuarioInclusao] [int] NOT NULL,
[DataAlteracao] [datetime] NULL,
[ID_UsuarioAlteracao] [int] NULL,
[IDProduto] [int] NOT NULL,
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ficaria assim:

```
codigo  **138SHPN150 ** KTB135-S ** DYT233**
```

Comment: sobre o erro, no `sql-server` ao usar `group by` **todos os campos do select também devem estar no group by** ou **deve estar em funções de agregação** como `count` ou `sum`, por isso da erro. Sobre não aparecer, tente usar `LEFT JOIN` para testar. Para ajudar melhor seria legal colocar na pergunta os dados das duas tabelas

Comment: coloquei minhas duas tabelas

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como concatenar linhas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203992/como-concatenar-linhas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua consulta foi adaptada para gerar uma coluna nomeada como `codigos_conversao`.

- Para o critério "Os que não tiver código de conversão mostrar em branco" foi usado o IsNull(conteudo,'')
- Foi retirado o campo `c.Codigo` da consulta inicial que mostraria cada código que já está sendo concatenado na coluna `codigos_conversao` e asssim poderá obter sucesso com o `Distinct` da consulta.

Consulta a seguir:

```
SELECT distinct p.ID_Produto,p.CodigoInterno, p.Descricao, p.Localizacao, p.EstoqueAtual, c.IDProduto,
 IsNull(
         (SELECT DISTINCT convert(varchar(10), C1.Codigo) + ' ** '  AS codigos
                    FROM TB_ProdutoConversao C1 
                    where C1.IDProduto = P.ID_Produto
                      For XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),''
        ) as codigos_conversao
FROM TB_Produtos AS p 
Left JOIN tb_produtoConversao AS c ON ID_Produto = IDProduto
```

EDIT:

Outra solução possível, seria utilizar uma função que retornasse a concatenação desejada, porém teria que considerar a performance entre as soluções.

Claro que existem várias formas de fazer, aqui tentei ajudar com a utilização do `For XML PATH`.

Antes de postar a resposta, havia realizado testes. Esses testes foram publicados no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ea5a9/3) e disponibilizados abaixo também.

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TB_Produtos]    Script Date: 11/04/2021 03:31:02 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_Produtos](
    [ID_Produto] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CodigoInterno] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [Localizacao] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Descricao] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [CodigoCompra] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [DescricaoCompra] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [ValorCompraProduto] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [DataUltimaEntrada] [datetime] NULL,
    [DataUltimaSaida] [datetime] NULL,
    [DescricaoFaturamento] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Marca] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [EstoqueMinimo] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [EstoqueAtual] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [PrecoTabelaA] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [PrecoTabelaB] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [PrecoTabelaC] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [AlicotaIBPT] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [IVA] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [ReducaoICMS] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [AlicotaIPI] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Observacao] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [DataInclusao] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ID_UsuarioInclusao] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DataAlteracao] [datetime] NULL,
    [ID_UsuarioAlteracao] [int] NULL,
    [Conversao] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [ID_Unidade] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GiroMensal] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [IDUltimoFormecedorCompra] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DataUltimaCompra] [datetime] NULL,
    [NCM] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [CST] [nvarchar](20) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY];


INSERT INTO TB_Produtos (CodigoInterno,Localizacao,Descricao,CodigoCompra,DescricaoCompra,ValorCompraProduto,DataUltimaEntrada,DataUltimaSaida,DescricaoFaturamento,Marca,EstoqueMinimo,EstoqueAtual,PrecoTabelaA,PrecoTabelaB,PrecoTabelaC,AlicotaIBPT,IVA,ReducaoICMS,AlicotaIPI,Observacao,DataInclusao,ID_UsuarioInclusao,DataAlteracao,ID_UsuarioAlteracao,Conversao,ID_Unidade,GiroMensal,IDUltimoFormecedorCompra,DataUltimaCompra,NCM,CST) VALUES
     ('41.34605','PRATELEIRA A1','CORREIA DENTADA',NULL,NULL,10.00,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,2.00,4.00,3.00,2.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,NULL,'2021-04-10 00:00:00.000',1,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,25.00,125,NULL,NULL,NULL),
     ('4654','PRATELEIRA B1','JOGO DE JUNTAS MOTOR',NULL,NULL,12.00,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,10.00,30.00,12.00,10.00,8.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,NULL,'2021-04-10 00:00:00.000',1,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,25.00,125,NULL,NULL,NULL);
;

CREATE TABLE TB_ProdutoConversao (
    IDConversao int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Codigo nvarchar(max) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    Descricao nvarchar(max) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    DtExclusao datetime NULL,
    IdUsuarioExcluiu int NULL,
    DataAlteracao datetime NULL,
    ID_UsuarioAlteracao int NULL,
    IDProduto int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO TB_ProdutoConversao (Codigo,Descricao,DtExclusao,IdUsuarioExcluiu,DataAlteracao,ID_UsuarioAlteracao,IDProduto) VALUES
     ('138SHPN150',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1),
     ('KTB135-S',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1),
     ('DYT233',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from TB_Produtos
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ea5a9/3/0)**:

```
| ID_Produto | CodigoInterno |   Localizacao |            Descricao | CodigoCompra | DescricaoCompra | ValorCompraProduto | DataUltimaEntrada | DataUltimaSaida | DescricaoFaturamento |  Marca | EstoqueMinimo | EstoqueAtual | PrecoTabelaA | PrecoTabelaB | PrecoTabelaC | AlicotaIBPT | IVA | ReducaoICMS | AlicotaIPI | Observacao |         DataInclusao | ID_UsuarioInclusao | DataAlteracao | ID_UsuarioAlteracao | Conversao | ID_Unidade | GiroMensal | IDUltimoFormecedorCompra | DataUltimaCompra |    NCM |    CST |
|------------|---------------|---------------|----------------------|--------------|-----------------|--------------------|-------------------|-----------------|----------------------|--------|---------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|-------------|-----|-------------|------------|------------|----------------------|--------------------|---------------|---------------------|-----------|------------|------------|--------------------------|------------------|--------|--------|
|          1 |      41.34605 | PRATELEIRA A1 |      CORREIA DENTADA |       (null) |          (null) |                 10 |            (null) |          (null) |               (null) | (null) |             2 |            4 |            3 |            2 |            1 |           1 |   1 |           1 |          1 |     (null) | 2021-04-10T00:00:00Z |                  1 |        (null) |              (null) |    (null) |          1 |         25 |                      125 |           (null) | (null) | (null) |
|          2 |          4654 | PRATELEIRA B1 | JOGO DE JUNTAS MOTOR |       (null) |          (null) |                 12 |            (null) |          (null) |               (null) | (null) |            10 |           30 |           12 |           10 |            8 |           1 |   1 |           1 |          1 |     (null) | 2021-04-10T00:00:00Z |                  1 |        (null) |              (null) |    (null) |          1 |         25 |                      125 |           (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select * from TB_ProdutoConversao
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ea5a9/3/1)**:

```
| IDConversao |     Codigo | Descricao | DtExclusao | IdUsuarioExcluiu | DataAlteracao | ID_UsuarioAlteracao | IDProduto |
|-------------|------------|-----------|------------|------------------|---------------|---------------------|-----------|
|           1 | 138SHPN150 |    (null) |     (null) |           (null) |        (null) |              (null) |         1 |
|           2 |   KTB135-S |    (null) |     (null) |           (null) |        (null) |              (null) |         1 |
|           3 |     DYT233 |    (null) |     (null) |           (null) |        (null) |              (null) |         1 |
```

**Query 3 - Proposta como resposta para a pergunta**:

```
SELECT distinct p.ID_Produto,p.CodigoInterno, p.Descricao, p.Localizacao, p.EstoqueAtual, c.IDProduto,
 IsNull(
         (SELECT DISTINCT convert(varchar(10), C1.Codigo) + ' ** '  AS codigos
                    FROM TB_ProdutoConversao C1 
                    where C1.IDProduto = P.ID_Produto
                      For XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),''
        ) as codigos_conversao
FROM TB_Produtos AS p 
Left JOIN tb_produtoConversao AS c ON ID_Produto = IDProduto
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ea5a9/3/2)**:

```
| ID_Produto | CodigoInterno |            Descricao |   Localizacao | EstoqueAtual | IDProduto |                    codigos_conversao |
|------------|---------------|----------------------|---------------|--------------|-----------|--------------------------------------|
|          1 |      41.34605 |      CORREIA DENTADA | PRATELEIRA A1 |            4 |         1 | 138SHPN150 ** DYT233 ** KTB135-S **  |
|          2 |          4654 | JOGO DE JUNTAS MOTOR | PRATELEIRA B1 |           30 |    (null) |                                      |
```

Comment: Clarck Maciel, Muito Obrigado pela ajuda e pela explicação funcionou perfeitamente até mais meu amigo

Answer (score 2):

Aproveitando a resposta do @Sorak aqui: [como-concatenar-linhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203992/como-concatenar-linhas)

Precisa concatenar as multiplas linhas da tabela **TB_ProdutoConversao** e adicionar isso ao seu `SELECT`. Isso pode ser feito com `JOIN`, mas uma forma simples é fazer uma *subquery*, que seria assim:

```
select STRING_AGG(codigo,' ** ') from tb_produtoConversao
 group by idProduto;
```

Isso vai retornar os valores assim: *"138SHPN150 ** KTB135-S ** DYT233"*

Veja que **para esse exemplo usei a *function* `STRING_AGG`, assimindo que esteja usando SQL Server 2017+**, mas poderia fazer com `SUBSTRING/FOR XML` como tem no outro exemplo da resposta do link acima.

Voltando à query, basta juntar essa *subquery* para ter o resultado:

```
select p.ID_Produto,
       p.CodigoInterno, 
       p.Descricao, 
       p.Localizacao, 
       p.EstoqueAtual, 
       c.IDProduto, 
       (select STRING_AGG(c2.codigo,',')
          from tb_produtoConversao c2
         where c2.IDProduto=c.IDProduto
         group by c2.IDProduto) as Codigos
  from TB_Produtos as p 
  join tb_produtoConversao as c on ID_Produto = IDProduto  
  group by p.ID_Produto,
       p.CodigoInterno, 
       p.Descricao, 
       p.Localizacao, 
       p.EstoqueAtual, 
       c.IDProduto
```

Pode ver funcionando aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6d40d/15

Observe que adicionei só as colunas e dados relevantes para testar o resultado.
A se notar também:

- todos os campos fora o campo campo da *subquery* foram adicionados ao `group by`;
- na *subquery*, fiz `join` da "tb_produtoConversao" com ela mesma (alias **c2** e **c**), para retorne os codigos agregados corretos em relação à query principal (tb_produtoConversao alias **c**);

Comment: Ricardo Muito obrigado pela ajuda funcionou perfeitamente, estou aprendendo a fazer procedure pq. minha aplicação uso Linql e ficou lento os acessos e com esta consulta ficou mais rapido Vlw